# Select elements from list using a Zipf-like selection in python

Tags: python, list, numpy, distribution

Is it possible to select one element from a list using python following the Zipf distribution?

Suppose I have a list:

```
objlist = ['Here', 'in', 'the', 'wall', 'why']
```

So far, I have seen https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.zipf.html
but I cannot figure out the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean the actual frequency of these words in the English language?

Comment: Yes. I want to select the elements according to zipfs distribution. If i understand your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the output of `numpy.random.zipf(shape_parameter)` as the index for your list. However there is the problem that the zipf distribution is unbound and the value may be larger than your index. So insert it in a `try:` `except:` block.
When you run your code multiple times, there will be different values drawn form your list. However, because the zipf distribution is unbound and your list index is not, it will not be exactly zipf distributed.

Saple code:

```
objlist = ['Here', 'in', 'the', 'wall', 'why']
index = np.random.zipf([1.2, 1.2])
for idx in index:
    if idx < len(objlist):
        print(objlist[idx])
    else: 
        print "Index {} exceed list".format(idx)
```

[Wikipedia: Zipf Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_distribution)

Comment: Hhm interesting suggestion. Is ti possible to set an example of code? It is a little bit tricky for me because i cannot understand the distribution.

Comment: Very useful. One last question. If i want to select 2 values according to this, how can achive this?

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote if you like it. It's at leat some reward for the work you didn't pay for ;)

Answer (score 2):

To select according to the actual empirical Zipf distribution, you first need a table of the frequencies of English words. If the 100,000 most frequent will do you can get one [here](http://1.1o1.in/en/webtools/semantic-depth).

That's a pdf, text is easier to handle, so convert it, on linux you can do

> > > pdftotext freq100000.pdf

This will create a text file freq100000.txt which you can use with the following little script

```
import re
import numpy as np

record = re.compile('[0-9]+ [0-9]+ [a-z]+')
data = {}
for line in open('freq100000.txt'):
    m = record.match(line.strip())
    if not m is None:
        rank, freq, word = m.group(0).split()
        data[word] = int(rank), int(freq)

def rel_freqs(wlist):
    freqs = np.array([data[word.lower()][1] for word in wlist])
    ps = np.add.accumulate(freqs)
    choice = np.searchsorted(ps, np.random.randint(ps[-1]))
    return choice

rel_freqs(['Here', 'in', 'the', 'wall', 'why'])
```

The function `rel_freqs` randomly selects a word from a list and returns its index. The probability of drawing a word is proportional to its frequency of  occurrence in English.

Comment: Ok, i understand your point and thank you. But i am newbie with distributions and i am tangle with this example. I want to adapt this in case of my list and it's difficult

Comment: Ok, let's try step-by-step: Did you succeed in (1) downloading the dictionary? (2) converting it to text? (3) running the script? - I'll add a line showing the function call.

Answer (score 0):

I hope im not misunderstanding your demands, here is my code:

```
import random
objlist = ['Here', 'in', 'the', 'wall', 'why']
print random.choice(objlist)
```

Comment: this simply selects value randomly.I want to follow the zips distribution in selection.